WP_Users_List_Table::display() not working
<?php
if (!class_exists('WP_Users_List_Table')) {
    require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/class-wp-users-list-table.php';
}
$user_list_table = new WP_Users_List_Table();
$user_list_table->prepare_items();
$user_list_table->display();
?>


The users are there, but they don't get rendered. Has anyone encountered the same issue?
